# One word for "not yet participated"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find an appropriate single word that means 'have not yet participated/not yet joined (and are being urged to join).'

Context: I want a shorter way to say 'List of people who have not yet joined'

Non-participants comes up but the context sounds wrong to me.

Does *pending list* sound good?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because choosing names for software constructs is explicitly off-topic according to our Help Center.

Comment: I would likely say "just a light shower", but my wife would give me a disgusted look.

Comment: *Pending* suggests those waiting to join. But is this a list of everyone in the world who's not a member, or is there some other criterion? And what about non-member etc?

Answer (score 3):

In the business world, these potential clients are called '**prospects**'.

[**Prospect**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prospect) (Merriam-Webster)

Noun

6
a: a potential buyer or customer
b: a likely candidate for a job or position